# obtener los elementos de una fila y mostrar en una pagina aparte en javascript, php, html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, datatables

```js
function detalle(item_id){

}
```

```html
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Fabricante</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th><center>Gramos</center></th>
                <th><center>Precio</center></th>
                <th>
                    <center>Acciones</center>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

<?php foreach($items as $it): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $it['item_code']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $it['item_name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $it['item_brand']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $it['item_type_desc']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $it['item_grams']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $it['item_price']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                           <center>
                               <button onclick="detalle('<?= $it['item_id']; ?>');" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Editar</button></center>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

tengo eso, un foreach que muestra los item, almacenado en una base de datos.
[image: muestra eso]

lo que no se, es como hago que cuando haga clik en el boton detalle me mande a una nueva pagina mostrando los detalles de esa fila, clickeado. estoy tratando de hacer algo dentro de la funcion detalle en javascript pero no han funcionado, ya que no manejo mucho javascript. espero su ayuda

Comment: que intentaste hasta el momento ? , y te sugiero para que sea bien recibida la pregunta , que coloques el codigo

Comment: @Hernelio Long Bienvenido, además de lo que dice Bruno te invito a leer [mcve]

Comment: Puedes usar Ajax igual te recomiendo plantear mejor tu pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como la información la tienes en PHP y la vas a mostrar en una función de Javascript, primero debes codificarlo en JSON (PHP) y posteriormente decodificarlo (Javascript).

El código resultante sería:

### PHP

```
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Fabricante</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th><center>Gramos</center></th>
                <th><center>Precio</center></th>
                <th>
                    <center>Acciones</center>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

<?php foreach($items as $it): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $it['item_code']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $it['item_name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $it['item_brand']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $it['item_type_desc']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $it['item_grams']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $it['item_price']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                           <center>
                               <button onclick="detalle('<?= json_encode($it); ?>');" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Editar</button></center>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

### Javascript

```
function detalle(item){
    var obj = JSON.parse(item);
    var myWindow = window.open("", "Detalles");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>Nombre: " + obj.item_name + "</p><p>Precio: " + obj.item_price+ "</p>");
}
```